# Htaccess giving me too many redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need help modifying my htaccess file.  I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^phpbb3.*$     http://mydomain.com/phpbb3/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordit
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/wordit/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Originally I only had:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordit
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/wordit/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Which I need to keep.  But I'm not sure how to incorporate the new rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^phpbb3.*$ http://mydomain.com/phpbb3/ [R=301,L]
```

How do I need to format my redirect?

Comment: add `RewriteRule ^phpbb3.*$ http://mydomain.com/phpbb3/ [R=301,L]` at the end

Comment: i still get Failed To Open page...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what is happening: The rewritten URL coming out of your new rule actually matches the rule itself, so it just loops and loops and loops.

A very simple modification might work:

```
RewriteRule ^phpbb3[^/]+$ http://mydomain.com/phpbb3/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thats basically what I had, now I have this:Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^phpbb3[^/]+$ http://www.mydomain.com/phpbb3/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordit
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/wordit/$1 [R=302,L]

The second one is the original one and it redirects my domain.com to my domain.com/wordit.  I need it because my site is at that folder but I installed a phpbb3 at my domain.com/phpbb3.  So i decided to add the first one in this list which should take my domain.com to my domain.com/php/, how do i do this